# Send pdf documents from php web service

Tags: php, web-services, pdf

I need to create a php webservice to send pdf files to an iPad application. I don't know the number of files, I will be sent a last sync date and web service must send all documents after that date.

If it was only one file, I guess I could do it using headers to set content type but how can I send multiple documents?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zip all the PDF documents after the specified date and bundle using PHP Zip library and send them in the content type as application/zip

From the receiving side, they will unzip and use the documents.

Comment: That's a good approach, thank you. I will propose to Ios developer and consider. Another idea is to send an index of pdf files and let the app request one file each time but I understand this is different point of view than my question in the first time. (sorry for my english)

Answer (score 0):

An easier approach might be to merge all the pdfs into one using fpdf.

This would allow the browser to handle display and saving though it does leave the user in the position of having to manage larger files.  It really depends on what the data is for as to whether this approach will work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i can't do that :)   pdfs are product catalogues to be sent to clients and they must be independent